# Trying to create a draw-line event that will allow the user to draw a line between 2 labels and detect which label the line has been drawn from and to

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I want to draw a line from 1 label to another label and have the programme be able to record which label the line has been drawn from and to.

Also, I need the programme to be able to draw 3 lines at once and ensure it only 3 lines are drawn at any one point. ( Eg if a 4th line is created the previous line will be deleted ) and a way to reset / clear the lines.

I'm have been unable to 
1. Draw the line within the programme
2. Make the line record from which textbox it has been drawn from and to

I have not yet attempted to make it be able to draw multiple lines or limit the amount of lines drawn.

Could someone please help?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! -  Also: Do tell us about the user interface you want to create!!

Comment: Apologies, I have added the tag now TaW. Could you elaborate on what you mean by user interface - it's a quiz so ut will be relatively simple.

Comment: What action will the user do and what graphic consequences will they have?

Comment: The user will draw a line from one label to another, this will appear visually as a line on the windows form. This line will indicate which label they are matching to which ( eg "Match the correct word to the correct color" if one label said "red" and the other label displayed a red back color they user would drag their mouse from one label to the other , matching them and creating a line between the two labels. I'm having a really difficult time making this work.

Comment: So you want a free-hand drawing? Or simply click on one label and select it and then click on the second and create a straight line between them?

Comment: I wanted it to be freehand, yes.

Comment: You can look up 'draw free-hand line winforms' for the drawing part. The first hurdle is getting the events right: You can code commen MouseDown and MOuseUp events for all Labels. Here the trick is to release the capture: `Label lbl = sender as Label;  lbl.Capture = false;`. Then you can store the 1st label in the MDown and create an entry in a List<T> in the MUp event. Use the container.MouseMOve event to collect the Points and save the collection in the List. Invalidate in the Move and in the MUp evenbt to trigger Paint. There use DrawCurve foreach List element and also for the current one..

Comment: Ok, thanks for helping me.  Iv egot the line drawing to work but I'm still having trouble with the events that will detect in which textbox the line starts and ends. You said to create an entry in a List<T> in the MDown event, I'm not sure what you want me to enter - the object sender? I've done this so farList<Label> labels = new List<Label> ; labels.Add((Label)sender);. I'm also unclear on how to collect the points and save them in the list using the mouse move event. why do I need to use DrawCurve if I am already able to draw my line?Sorry for the questions , I'm quite new to this language

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but I'll be away for two days. I'll write a proper answer on Wedenesday. Til then: Do explain why you switch talking about TextBoxes and Labels, which are quite different things. The string and ending controls are indeed the sender object in the MDwn sn -Up event. You need to cast them to Control or Label.. - I had asked about freehand drawing. If you actually want just straight lines you don't need to collect list of points. It is often a good idea to create a class that hold the data needed..

Comment: .. Here a ConnectorLine class could involve two Labels and maybe two connection points and a color or a pen width and text etc.. Then you create an array ot a List<ConnectorLine >.. For straight lines use g.DrawLine, of course.

Comment: Hi, sorry if I didn't make it clear in the last part but I have already been able to make the freehand drawing work, what I'm trying to do now is figure out how to find in which label the line started and ended. Apologies for using the word textbix instead of labels in my last comment - I'm too used to talking about Microsoft word.

Comment: It is the sender param you want. If the events are indeed hooked up to the labels.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to draw lines u have to use the paint event of the picturebox. I'm not sure if this is a must have, but I do it always like this.